# ng-grid How to set separate style for last row

Tags: angular-ui, ng-grid

I am trying to display some aggregate value (like total) in the last row of an ng-grid. The style and css class of the last row needs to be different than the other cells in that column. How to acheive this?

The cellTemplate in a column definition applies to all cells in that column, but in my case I need to have a different style for the last row in that column. Can anyone please suggest me a solution.

Thanks
Sudipta

Answer (score 2):

I was able to add a class to the last row through a plugin:

```
function ngGridAddClassToLastRow(className) {
    var self = this;
    self.grid = null;
    self.scope = null;
    self.init = function (scope, grid, services) {
        self.domUtilityService = services.DomUtilityService;
        self.grid = grid;
        self.scope = scope;
        var addClass = function () {
            var lastRow = self.scope.renderedRows[self.scope.renderedRows.length - 1];
            lastRow.elm[0].className = lastRow.elm[0].className + ' ' + className;
        };
        self.scope.$watch(grid.config.data, addClass);
    };
}
```

And with this added to the `gridOptions`:

```
...
plugins: [new ngGridAddClassToLastRow('<some class name>'),
...
```

And of course add some css, e.g. in my case:

```
.lastRow {
    border-bottom: 0px;
}
```

That worked for me.  I cannot say for certain that is the way to go since, needless to say, i'm a noob with Angular and ngGrid.  I've constructed the plugin from [flexible height plugin](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/tree/master/plugins).

Answer (score 0):

You can set a special property "isLast" (or however you like to name it) of the item that should be displayed in the last row. This item can be accessed through `row.entity.isLast`.

... somewhere in your controller ....

```
$scope.getRowClass = function(row) {
    return row.entity.isLast === true ? 'lastRow' : '';
}
```

... somewhere inside the gridOptions ...

```
rowTemplate: '<div ng-style="{ \'cursor\': row.cursor }" ng-repeat="col in renderedColumns" ng-class="[col.colIndex(), getRowClass(row)]" class="ngCell {{col.cellClass}}">....</div>'
```

Based on the `.lastRow` class you could define a custom style for the last grid row.